# Unable to showing navigation with Title In swift UI

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, navigationbar, tabview

I am using tab bar for with three tab for showing the data form api call . I added the required property for showing the navigation at top with title . Any reason it not showing it at top of the app .

Here is my content view code .

```
       import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var selection = 0
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewModel: FruitsViewModel

    var body: some View {

        TabView(selection: $selection) {

            NavigationView { TabListView(fruit: viewModel.fruits)}.tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                Text("List View")
            } .navigationBarTitle("Fruit List ", displayMode: .inline)
                .accentColor(.red)
                .onAppear() {
                    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
                }

                .tag(0)


            NavigationView {GridListView(fruit: viewModel.fruits)}.tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "bookmark.circle.fill")
                Text("Collection View")
            }.navigationBarTitle("Fruit List ", displayMode: .inline)
                .accentColor(.red)
                .onAppear() {
                    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
                }

                .tag(1)

            NavigationView {WebListView()}.tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                Text("Web View")
            }.navigationBarTitle("Fruit List ", displayMode: .inline)
                .accentColor(.red)
                .onAppear() {
                    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
                }
        }.tag(2)

    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here is the TabList code .

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabListView: View {

    let fruit: [Fruits]
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewModel: FruitsViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                
                ForEach(viewModel.fruits) { fruits in
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: FruitDetailsView(fruit: fruits)) {
                        FruitsRowList(fruit: fruits)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Fruit List")
        .onAppear {
            Task {
                await viewModel.getFruits()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result on simulator .. It just collapsed with entire view when I scroll down it .
[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251919/discussion-on-question-by-mohammad-unable-to-showing-navigation-with-title-in-sw); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order is very important in SwiftUI, Each tab should have its own `NavigationView` or `NavigationStack`.

`tabItem` should be attached to the `NavigationView` and `navigationTitle` should go inside the `NavigationView`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    //@EnvironmentObject private var viewModel: FruitsViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            
            NavigationView {
                Text("TabListView(fruit: viewModel.fruits)")
                    .navigationBarTitle("Fruit List ", displayMode: .inline)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                Text("List View")
            }
            .accentColor(.red)
            .onAppear() {
                UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
            }
            
            .tag(0)
            
            
            NavigationView {
                Text("GridListView(fruit: viewModel.fruits)")
                    .navigationBarTitle("Fruit List ", displayMode: .inline)
            }.tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "bookmark.circle.fill")
                Text("Collection View")
            }
            .accentColor(.red)
            .onAppear() {
                UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
            }
            
            .tag(1)
            
            NavigationView {
                Text("WebListView()")
                    .navigationBarTitle("Fruit List ", displayMode: .inline)
            }.tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                Text("Web View")
                    .accentColor(.red)
                    .onAppear() {
                        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
                    }
            }
            .tag(2)
        }
    }
}
```